# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot boot - stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Ubuntu does not boot. First timed happened after a freeze that required a hard shutdown.

You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
press enter for maintenance
(or press control-d to continue):
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
Failed to start default target: transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction

I looked over the forums and tried a few fixes. I believe I made it worse.

I can boot on a live usb.

I found the files I have in my /home when booting on a live usb but have not managed to tranfer them from the /home to a storage hard drive on the same machine.

I believe following one of the proposed fixes, I might have destroyed the boot partition on the ssd where ubuntu was installed.

I would need a step by step "hold my hand" method as I am only a simple user.

At this stage, I'd just like to save things that were saved in my /home and try re-installing. Finding out in the process whether I fried the ssd or damaged parts of it would be a plus.

Thanks.

**Adding a couple of things that might help**.

If I press enter, then I am in a "terminal like" mode where I can try and do a number of things.

I can access the /home/xavier directory where I can see all the documents save there.

However, I cannot mount the hdd on which I would like to transfer those files.

When I boot on a live usb, I can see my files and the second hdd but cannot move files from one to the other. My machine freezes as soon as I try doing anything.

I am typing this one another machine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: after booting and getting this terminal prompt, what is the result of typing `ls` please?

Comment: All I get is: snap

Comment: In snap I have:
bare
bin
canonical-livepatch
core
core18
core20
core22
firefox
gimp
gnome-3-28-1804
gnome-42-22-4
gtk2-common-themes
gtk-common-themes
handbrake-jz
mypdfsigner
pygt-runtime-core20
readme
snapd
snapd-desktop-integration
snap-store
vlc

Comment: I probably should have added I am root@mycomputer:~#

Comment: Does `fdisk -l` or `parted -l` find a harddrive? Is a harddrive detectet in your Uefi/Bios menu?

Comment: yes, fdisk -ll  finds:
34 loop disks 
sda - my ssd 5 partitions
/dev/sda1 BIOS boot
/dev/sda2 EFI System
/dev/sda3 linux swap
dev/sda4 Solaris boot 
dev/sda5 solaris root
and the two other hdd in the machine
sdb which is my storage and I can see, read and use under live usb boot
sdc an hdd from a dead computer which had useful documents on it. it has two partitions sdc1 and sdc2, both HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

All those disks are detected in bios. I need to get through bios to boot up on a live usb. All hardware is there.

Comment: From live-session you can make filesystemcheck. In live-session `sudo blkid` than you can see which filesystems you have.

Comment: SSD OOS - all looking normal but all corrupt and nothing working.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nobody As I mentioned, blkid was showing me all hard drives and partitions but hardware was likely damaged as nothing could really be fixed.